# Om Next subquery doesn't have effect on sub component props

Tags: clojurescript, om

Reading this Om Next tutorial page [Components, Identity & Normalization](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Components%2C-Identity-%26-Normalization), I thought the subquery from the subcomponent (Person component) is used to populate the Person's props. But changing the query from

```
'[:name :points :age]
```

to

```
'[]
```

doesn't break the app. Could you help me understand how the parser invokes read methods from these component/query tree.

The entire code from the page is below.

```
(def init-data
  {:list/one [{:name "John" :points 0}
              {:name "Mary" :points 0}
              {:name "Bob"  :points 0}]
   :list/two [{:name "Mary" :points 0 :age 27}
              {:name "Gwen" :points 0}
              {:name "Jeff" :points 0}]})

;; -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Parsing

(defmulti read om/dispatch)

(defn get-people [state key]
  (let [st @state]
    (into [] (map #(get-in st %)) (get st key))))

(defmethod read :list/one
  [{:keys [state] :as env} key params]
  {:value (get-people state key)})

(defmethod read :list/two
  [{:keys [state] :as env} key params]
  {:value (get-people state key)})

(defmulti mutate om/dispatch)

(defmethod mutate 'points/increment
  [{:keys [state]} _ {:keys [name]}]
  {:action
   (fn []
     (swap! state update-in
            [:person/by-name name :points]
            inc))})

(defmethod mutate 'points/decrement
  [{:keys [state]} _ {:keys [name]}]
  {:action
   (fn []
     (swap! state update-in
            [:person/by-name name :points]
            #(let [n (dec %)] (if (neg? n) 0 n))))})

;; -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;; Components

(defui Person
  static om/Ident
  (ident [this {:keys [name]}]
    [:person/by-name name])
  static om/IQuery
  (query [this]
    '[])
  Object
  (render [this]
    (println "Render Person" (-> this om/props :name))
    (let [{:keys [points name age] :as props} (om/props this)]
      (dom/li nil
              (dom/label nil (str name ", points: " points ", age: " age))
              (dom/button
                #js {:onClick
                     (fn [e]
                       (om/transact! this
                                     `[(points/increment ~props)]))}
                "+")
              (dom/button
                #js {:onClick
                     (fn [e]
                       (om/transact! this
                                     `[(points/decrement ~props)]))}
                "-")))))

(def person (om/factory Person {:keyfn :name}))

(defui ListView
  Object
  (render [this]
    (println "Render ListView" (-> this om/path first))
    (let [list (om/props this)]
      (apply dom/ul nil
             (map person list)))))

(def list-view (om/factory ListView))

(defui RootView
  static om/IQuery
  (query [this]
    (let [subquery (om/get-query Person)]
      `[{:list/one ~subquery} {:list/two ~subquery}]))
  Object
  (render [this]
    (println "Render RootView")
    (let [{:keys [list/one list/two]} (om/props this)]
      (apply dom/div nil
             [(dom/h2 nil "List A")
              (list-view one)
              (dom/h2 nil "List B")
              (list-view two)]))))

(def reconciler
  (om/reconciler
    {:state  init-data
     :parser (om/parser {:read read :mutate mutate})}))

(om/add-root! reconciler
              RootView (gdom/getElement "app"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading [this](https://github.com/awkay/om/wiki/Om-Next-Overview) now I know that only the top level queries are processed by the parser. And you are responsible for providing your own reads for subqueries by accessing `(:query env)`.